# How necessary are mathematics in programming?

Tags: math

I read on many forums for "Do I need mathematic-skills to code?" (and such), but my question is slightly different.

What I want to know is: How much mathematics do you **really need** to graduate (with high marks) in 'Computer Engineering' or 'Information Technology' and is it hard?

By the way, I love mathematics, eventhough I'm not good enough at it (I won 3 math olympiads but I struggle from self-esteem).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO doesn't provide education advice

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of programming work you do.  Web development?  High school algebra and perhaps statistics.  Scientific computing and graphics?  Lots of calculus and linear algebra.  A better question is "How much mathematics do I have to know to consider myself an educated person in a technological society?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To graduate - You'll need it for sure. An easy example are **integrals**, **derivatives** and stuff like that. A lot of subjects, at least in my university requires a basic understanding of maths.

Another thing is what kind of a programmer you wanna be. Sure I guess you do not always have to use math's while writing **HTML** code or so.

On the other hand - for **algorithmic** stuff you couldn't get away without it :)

all in all, To graduate in IT you have to know math, but to code, not always.